# How to stop updating a cell once certain qualifications are met

Tags: excel

I'm creating a checklist. When all the requirements are met, I want a "date completed" cell to change to that date, then never update again.

I understand how to use if statements to make the cell blank until the qualifications are met, but I don't know if it's possible to tell it to pull a TODAY() value from another cell only when the last qualification is met. I'm thinking there is probably a VBA way to do it, but I would really like to do this using native functions if possible.

Here is some sample code for the box in question:

```
=IF(A2*B2*C2*D2*E2=1,TODAY(),"")
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: So what do you get with this approach? Wrong result?

Comment: I get a date that consistently updates to the new TODAY() each time I update the whole spreadsheet. I would rather it update to TODAY() when I complete the checklist, then stay that same date from then on. That way I can track what dates I completed each checklist on.

Comment: You would need to use vba and a worksheet_change macro I believe.

Comment: Search for `excel time stamp` and you will find many VBA examples.

Comment: That did it teylen, I actually found a non-VBA answer!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it without VBA:

1. Turn on "iterative calculations" by going to File>Options>Formulas>Enable iterative calculation
2. Use a self-referential formula: (This would be in F2)

   =IF(A2*B2*C2*D2*E2=1,IF(F2="",NOW(),F2),"")

[This](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/01/08/timestamps-excel-formula-help/) is the article I found (with teylen's help) that explained it.